# Is there a way to sign out a different account when it gets deactivated?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to sign out of a different account when I deactivate the account. Here's the code I have right now, however, it's signing me out of my current account

```
  const authentication = useAuthentication();
  const { isAuthenticated, signOut } = authentication;

  if (!isAuthenticated) return null;

  const { adminId, adminEmail, onAdminDeactivate } = props;
  const deactivateAdminAction = async () => {
    await deactivateAdminHandler(adminId);
    if (onAdminDeactivate) onAdminDeactivate();
    signOut(adminId);
  };
```

Then I call deactivateAdminFunction on click of a button, and I'm able to get the adminId fine as I'm able to deactivate the correct admin. Does anyone know by chance?

Thanks!